# Inferno Adze not used when mining (Wielded)

Tags: runescape

I am trying to use the [Inferno Adze](https://runescape.wiki/w/Inferno_adze) as a pickaxe. However every time my character pulls up a bronze pickaxe (from my toolbelt) instead. It should work as a rune pickaxe. I have searched all over the forums for this bug, but no luck.

Anyone has any idea why my toolbelt is being prioritised, even though I am wielding the adze.

Comment: Do you have 41+ mining?

Comment: yes I have 65 mining & 90 wc. It worked before, now I logged in after 3-4 years of inactivity. It doesn't work.

Comment: Given the 3 - 4 years of inactivity, perhaps you were logged into a non-members server? That's the only thing I can think of that would cause it to function the way you are describing. My account hasn't had a membership is a very long time, but yet I am still wielding member gear when I log in. My attacks are equivalent to using fists rather than the Bandos GS

Comment: I tried several member worlds, no luck. It works as a hatchet, but not as a pickaxe. Tried contacting Jagex about this bug - but I have never received an answer for any of my inquires.